# rsync is creating a folder called Archive under /Volumes instead of copying files to mounted share /Volumes/Archive

Tags: rsync, disk-volume

I am moving data from a Drobo 5D to a NAS (FreeNAS). I am using this command:

```
sudo rsync -a --stats --progress "/Volumes/Drobo 5D" "/Volumes/Archive"
```

Obviously, before I run the command, I mounted the  `Archive` volume using Finder (browsed the network, found the server, clicked on the share). However, for some reason, `rsync` is creating a folder under `/Volumes` called `Archive` instead of using the mounted `Archive` volume. This is filling my system drive, instead of copying the data to the correct destination.

Here you can see the two `Archive` volumes:

[image]

Here's the output of the `mount` command:

```
/dev/disk0s2 on / (hfs, local, with quotas, journaled)
devfs on /dev (devfs, local, nobrowse) 
/dev/disk1s2 on /Volumes/Macintosh SSD 2 (hfs, local, journaled) 
map -hosts on /net (autofs, nosuid, automounted, nobrowse) 
map auto_home on /home (autofs, automounted, nobrowse) 
map -fstab on /Network/Servers (autofs, automounted, nobrowse) 
/dev/disk4s2 on /Volumes/Drobo 5D (hfs, local, journaled) 
/dev/disk5s2 on /Volumes/Macintosh iSCSI (hfs, local, journaled) 
/dev/disk3s2 on /Volumes/Backup (hfs, local, journaled) 
/dev/disk2s2 on /Volumes/Time Machine (hfs, local, journaled) 
//Matthew@Megatron._smb._tcp.local/Archive on /Volumes/Archive-1 (smbfs, nodev, nosuid, mounted by Admin)
```

Here's the output of the `ls -l /Volumes` command:

```
drwxr-xr-x+  3 root  wheel    102 Jun 21 22:16 Archive
drwx------   1 Admin  staff  16384 Jun 22 08:07 Archive-1 
drwxrwxr-x  16 Admin  staff    612 Jun  2 09:43 Backup 
drwxrwx---+ 43 root   admin   1530 Jun 22 08:00 Drobo 5D
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root   wheel      1 Jun 22 08:00 Macintosh SSD -> /
drwxrwxr-x  17 Admin  staff    646 Jun 22 08:00 Macintosh SSD 2
drwxrwxr-x  10 root   admin    408 Jun 14 08:19 Macintosh iSCSI
drwxrwxr-x  14 Admin  staff    544 Jun  2 09:43 Time Machine
```

Since posting this question, I have wondered if putting the destination path in quotes makes any difference. Commonsense tells me no, but best not to assume such things.

My questions are:

1. Why isn't `rsync` using the already mounted `Archive` volume?
2. How do I correctly remove the `Archive` folder from the `Volumes` folder?

Comment: It would be useful if you would add to your post the command `mount` and the output.

Comment: I mounted the volume using Finder (question updated). Is mounting the volume using Finder less effective than mounting using the command line?

Comment: Not necessarily, `mount` with no options or arguments, just lists the file systems that are mounted. The picture suggests that you may have ghost volumes mounted.

Comment: I'm not sure what a ghost volume is. I can confirm the Archive volume on the FreeNAS server is mounted and accessible. The Archive folder under Volumes appears to be a local folder.

Comment: We want to see the mount information as it  gives more information (or at least the same info in one place) than the GUI

Comment: If you unmount the real Archive volume, delete the erroneous /Volumes/Archive folder and then remount the real Archive volume, then run your `rsync` command, does it work properly?. If not, repeat and use a `/` at the end of the `source` and `destination` volume pathnames. If that fails, add the output of the `mount` command from Terminal to the OP.

Comment: @user3439894 that is one of my questions - how I do correctly delete the folder? Will Finder work or do I need to delete at command line and if so, what is the appropriate command?

Comment: Please let us help in helping you. Open Terminal, run `mount` and copy/paste the result into the question (as text). Do the same for `ls -l /Volumes`.

Comment: @Swisher Sweet, In Terminal, after the real Archive volume has been unmounted: `sudo rm -R /Volumes/Archive`

Comment: Sorry for the delay; had a production deployment to complete... pesky job. :)